# gdb mov instruction has 'no' influence on the register esp

Tags: assembly, gdb

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80483e4: file hello.c, line 6.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /PROG/1/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at hello.c:6
6       for(i=0;i<10;i++)

(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x080483d4 <+0>:     push   ebp
   0x080483d5 <+1>:     mov    ebp,esp
   0x080483d7 <+3>:     sub    esp,0x8
   0x080483da <+6>:     and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x080483dd <+9>:     mov    eax,0x0
   0x080483e2 <+14>:    sub    esp,eax
   0x080483e4 <+16>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x0
   0x080483eb <+23>:    cmp    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x9
   0x080483ef <+27>:    jle    0x80483f3 <main+31>
   0x080483f1 <+29>:    jmp    0x8048406 <main+50>
   0x080483f3 <+31>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x80484e4       <=this instruction 'doesn't have influence'
   0x080483fa <+38>:    call   0x80482f0 <printf@plt>
   0x080483ff <+43>:    lea    eax,[ebp-0x4]
   0x08048402 <+46>:    inc    DWORD PTR [eax]
   0x08048404 <+48>:    jmp    0x80483eb <main+23>
   0x08048406 <+50>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0804840b <+55>:    leave  
   0x0804840c <+56>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.

(gdb) nexti
0x080483eb  6       for(i=0;i<10;i++)
(gdb) nexti
0x080483ef  6       for(i=0;i<10;i++)
(gdb) nexti
7           printf("Hello, World!\n");
(gdb) i r esp
esp            0xbffff520   0xbffff520
(gdb) nexti
0x080483fa  7           printf("Hello, World!\n");
(gdb) i r esp
esp            0xbffff520   0xbffff520
(gdb) nexti
0x08048402  6       for(i=0;i<10;i++)
(gdb) i r esp
esp            0xbffff520   0xbffff520                         <=esp stays the same all the time



(gdb) quit
```

The instructions you see were build with gcc-3.3.6 (gcc -g hello.c), on a Gentoo system(i686). They affect the system to print 'Hello, World!' 10 times.

As you can see the `mov` instruction 'should' write the address 0x80484e4 in the register esp, but the command i r esp(info register esp) returns the same all the time.

I tried everything with different versions of gdb, I even tried it on different distros. However its the same all the time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The `mov` that you are referring to **does not write any value in the ESP register**.
This instruction writes an address in the memory location pointed at by ESP in preparation for the following `call` that expects an address for its argument.